# After .load event all jquery effects stopped

Tags: jquery

I have a .load event on my page,

it loads a page full of jquery effects like hide and show,

when load ends, the page appears but any jquery effect at this page does not work?

what can I do?

an example:

```
 $('#HomePosts').hide().load('fetch.php?do=homePosts',null,Response).slideDown(500);
```

fetch.php brings code like

```
<div class='freediv'>Content</div>
```

in my core.js there is code like

```
$('.freediv').css('boderd','1px solid black');
```

it doesn work when I load it but I work when I go to it through the browser?

Answer (score 0):

You want the animation to occur once the data is loaded, correct?

You need to place the slide down animation in the callback of the load function:

```
$('#HomePosts').hide().load('fetch.php?do=homePosts', function() {$(this).slideDown(500)});
```

Comment: i knw what are u talking about ,, im asking if the data loaded , the jquery effects at the loaded page does not work